# How can I retrieve and compare result values from threads?

Tags: c, pthreads

For an assignment, I'm trying to do a rock-paper-scissors game in C, using pthreads and focusing on barriers.

It should have an user-defined amount of players and number of rounds. Basic rock-paper-scissors rules ensues. For every thread/player that beats another, it adds a score for him, and for every tie, rng to decide who will get a score (fairness is not considered, this is mostly to focus on barriers). At the end I should present a winner.

> ```
> e.g. 5 players, 2 rounds. They played: Rock(0), Rock(0), Scissors(2), Paper(1), Paper(1).
>
> Round 1:
>
> Player 1 tied with Player 2, beat Player 3 and lost to Player 4 and 5
> Player 2 tied with Player 1, beat player 3 and lost to Player 4 and 5
> Player 3 lost to Player 1 and 2 and beat Player 4 and 5
> Player 4 beat Player 1 and 2, lost to Player 3 and tied with Player 5
> Player 5 beat Player 1 and 2, lost to Player 3 and tied with Player 4
>
> End score would be: 
> Player 1: 2 (RNG has chosen him)
> Player 2: 1
> Player 3: 2
> Player 4: 2
> Player 5: 3 (RNG has chosen him)
>
> Round 2
>
> ...
>
> Player 1: 4 (round 1: 2 + round 2: 2)
> Player 2: 2 (1+1)
> Player 3: 5 (2+3)
> Player 4: 4 (2+2)
> Player 5: 5 (3+2)
>
> Winner: Player 3 (RNG)
> ```

I think I managed to get the thread and barrier thing done, but I can't think of a way to do the scoring thing. I can retrieve the thread results in an ordely manner, but I can't figure how to keep track and compare with an n-number of players and results

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_barrier_t barrier;

void* game(void *id) {
    int player = *(int*)id;
    int random = (int)(void*)(&player);
    int play = random % 3;
    if (play == 0) {
        printf("Player %d: played Rock \n", player);
    }
    if (play == 1) {
        printf("Player %d: played Paper \n", player);
    }
    if (play == 2) {
        printf("Player %d: played Scissors \n", player);
    }

    pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier);

    return (void *)play;
}


int main() {
    system("cls");
    int PLAYERS;
    printf("Players: \n");
    scanf("%d", &PLAYERS);
    printf("\n");
    int i, j;
    pthread_t id[PLAYERS];
    int num_id[PLAYERS];
    void *play;

    pthread_barrier_init(&barrier, NULL, PLAYERS + 1);

    for (i=0; i < PLAYERS; i++) {
        num_id[i] = i;
        pthread_create(&id[i], NULL, game, &num_id[i]);
    }

    pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier);

    for (i=0; i < PLAYERS; i++) {
        pthread_join(id[i], &play);
        printf("The hand of %d was %d\n", i, play); //printf debug
    }

    pthread_barrier_destroy(&barrier);

    return 0;
}
```

Still no rounds because it's still WIP
What would be the best way to do it?

Comment: If I understand you correctly your problem has nothing to do with threads. (and is also wrong as you allready retrieved the result with join). Your problem seems only that you don't know how to evaluate an unknown amount of values, am I correct?

Comment: Probably yes. I don't know how to store these values and compare with each other. I know how to print them on the screen, but I don't know how to handle them yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [man pthread_join](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html):

```
int pthread_join(pthread_t thread, void **retval);
If retval is not NULL, then pthread_join() copies the exit status of
       the target thread (i.e., the value that the target thread supplied to
       pthread_exit(3)) into the location pointed to by retval
```

You return `play` variable value from each `game()`, yet you save it to the same variable, just save it to an array.

```
int main() {
    system("cls");
    int PLAYERS;
    printf("Players: \n");
    scanf("%d", &PLAYERS);
    printf("\n");
    int i, j;
    // using VLA from C99 isn't that much reliable, so i decided to use malloc here
    // pthread_t id[PLAYERS];
    pthread_t *id = malloc(sizeof(*id)*PLAYERS);
    // int num_id[PLAYERS];
    int *num_id = malloc(sizeof(*num_id)*PLAYERS);
    // void *play[PLAYERS];
    int *play = malloc(sizeof(*play)*PLAYERS);
    // maybe think of a structure here? 
    // struct player { pthread_t *id; int num_id; int play; } *players = malloc(sizeof(*players)*PLAYERS);

    pthread_barrier_init(&barrier, NULL, PLAYERS + 1);

    for (i=0; i < PLAYERS; i++) {
        num_id[i] = i;
        pthread_create(&id[i], NULL, game, &num_id[i]);
    }

    pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier);

    for (i=0; i < PLAYERS; i++) {
        pthread_join(id[i], (void*)&play[i]);
    }

    pthread_barrier_destroy(&barrier);

    for (i=0; i < PLAYERS; i++) {
        printf("The hand of %d was %d\n", i, play[i]);
    }
    // you want to compare first hand with second one?
    if (play[0] == play[1]) {
         printf("First two hands were the same.\n");
    }

    free(id);
    free(num_id);
    free(play);

    return 0;
}
```

But i think a better way would be to pass a pointer to some defined structure as the argument to threads, like this:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct player_s {
  pthread_t *id;
  int num_id; 
  int play;
};

pthread_barrier_t barrier;

void* game(void *arg0) {
    struct player_s *p = arg0;
    assert(p != NULL);
    int player = p->num_id;
    int random = player; // this is not random ;)
    int play = random % 3;
    if (play == 0) {
        printf("Player %d: played Rock \n", player);
    }
    if (play == 1) {
        printf("Player %d: played Paper \n", player);
    }
    if (play == 2) {
        printf("Player %d: played Scissors \n", player);
    }

    pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier);

    p->play = play; // save play variable

    return NULL;
}


int main() {
    system("cls");
    int PLAYERS;
    printf("Players: \n");
    scanf("%d", &PLAYERS);
    printf("\n");
    int i, j;
    struct player_s *players = malloc(sizeof(*players)*PLAYERS);
    assert(players != NULL);

    pthread_barrier_init(&barrier, NULL, PLAYERS + 1);

    for (i=0; i < PLAYERS; i++) {
        players[i].num_id = i;
        pthread_create(&players[i].id, NULL, game, &players[i]);
    }

    pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier);

    for (i=0; i < PLAYERS; i++) {
        pthread_join(players[i].id, NULL);
    }

    pthread_barrier_destroy(&barrier);

    for (i=0; i < PLAYERS; i++) {
         printf("The hand of %d was %d\n", i, players[i].play);
    }
    // you want to compare first hand with second one?
    if (players[0].play == players[1].play) {
         printf("First two hands were the same.\n");
    }
    // compare first hand with all the others regardless of the array size
    for(i = 0; i < PLAYERS; ++i) {
        printf("The first hand was %d and the %d hand played %d, so they ", players[0].play, i, players[i].play);
        if (players[0].play != players[i].play) {
            printf("differ!\n");
        } else {
            printf("are the same!\n");
        }
    }
    free(players);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The idea on the first example seems right to me, storing it on an array would do the trick I guess, but I still don't exactly know how can I compare it with all the other numbers, regardless of array size

Also, I found interesting the method using struct, but I couldn't run your code, so I couldn't understand it properly. I'm still not too good with struct

Comment: struct is used to combine variables together, there are many tutorials on the net. I fixed the compilation, run the code, and added comparision loop, which compares first hand with all hands and prints if they are the same or differ, regardless of the number of hands.